# Scrollable Table Keeping the headers always visible

Tags: html, css, jsp, html-table

I have a table which displays the data from a database. The `<tr>` and `<td>` are dynamically created using a for loop.

I want the data alone in that table to scroll with the `<th>` always visible so that user can see the headers while scrolling through the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using thead? i think this should work
.tbody{overflow:scroll; height:500px}

<thead>
  <tr><th>head1</th>....</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <!-- create <tr><td>h1r1</td></td> -->
</tbody>